# Bash if/else Loop Error

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax-error

Exactly as title says. Simple if statement in Bash. I've been trying to figure out why this loop isn't working and I haven't come up with anything for two days now. Insight would be appreciated.

```
declare -r TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N")

CHECK="$(grep -c "$TIMESTAMP" /var/log/host/logname.log)"
if [ "$CHECK" -eq 0 ]
then
     COLOR="green"
elif [ 0 -lt "$CHECK" ] && [ "$CHECK" -le 5 ]
     COLOR="yellow"
else
     COLOR="red"
fi
```

The COLOR var is something that is preset by the system I'm using. The red/yellow/green are all correct, something in either my syntax or logic is the issue, though I've been struggling to determine which. Thanks!

EDIT: My mistake. Early morning and question was rife with typos. I have fixed them. Error is as follows,

```
syntax error near unexpected token `else'
`     else'
```

Comment: I can't see your for loop. And the syntax highlighting on the code should already be suspicious: find the closing quotes of the string in the first line. Also "it doesn't work" is never enough information.

Comment: Please paste the error you get!!

Comment: I do not see a closing `"` at the first line of your script (`date` command)

Comment: That was a typo on here only. Sorry about that. And error has been pasted!

Comment: You really should include the error, which would have been `: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'` first, then after you corrected that, you'd have gotten `: syntax error near unexpected token `else'`

Comment: I was only getting the second error. No warning of unexpected EOF appeared.

Comment: Also, this is not a loop.  Loops are while, for, etc.  This will not repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a quote, and a then.

```
declare -r TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N")   # missing " here

CHECK="$(grep -c "$TIMESTAMP" /var/log/host/logname.log)"
if [ "$CHECK" -eq 0 ]; then
     COLOR="green"
elif [ 0 -lt "$CHECK" ] && [ "$CHECK" -le 5 ]; then    # missing then was here
     COLOR="yellow"
else
     COLOR="red"
fi
```

Comment: Ah! I did not realize I required a second "then" after using else/if. Solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, I'd personally reserve the capital letters for your read-only variable, and lower case the others.  It's a handy convention when trouble shooting/maintaining scripts later.

Comment: Now choose one of the answers as the correct one-- I don't care which, it's only SO rep :-)

Comment: I'll go ahead and change that up as well. I only started learning Bash a few weeks ago and only just started creating read only variables. Thanks! :)

Comment: Variables in all capital letters are actually reserved by the shell.

Comment: @chepner the shells reserved variables are in all caps and underscores, but not all capital letters are reserved by the shell.  Google's Shell Style Guide is a good resource for naming, but ultimately we will all argue what has worked in our own experience.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors, this may help

```
declare -r TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N")
CHECK="$(grep -c "$TIMESTAMP" /var/log/host/logname.log)"
if [ "$CHECK" -eq 0 ]
then
   COLOR="green"
elif [ 0 -lt "$CHECK" ] && [ "$CHECK" -le 5 ]
then
   COLOR="yellow"
else
   COLOR="green"
fi
```

Comment: You forgot `fi` :)

Comment: I was missing the "then" after my elif statement. Thanks for the help. :)